# RBAC implementation in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I am following the book 'Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5' for implementation of Rbac in Yii framework. I am a facing a problem in page 210 of the book which says:

"One other small change we made as to add a simple link from the project details
page so we could access this form form the application. The following line was
added to the project show.php view file's list of link options:

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::link('Add User To Project',
                 array('adduser','id'=>$model->project_Id));
?>
```

This gives us access to the new form.

Can anyone tell me what does the line mean and where to implement it??

Answer (score 3):

This line simply creates a totally standard HTML anchor tag with a link. In this case, the tag will look somewhat like this (I don't know what it will be exactly as I do not have the book and don't know how the sample application is set up):

```
<a href="index.php?r=something/adduser/id">Add User To Project</a>
```

See [CHtml by example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml#hh0) on the Yii wiki if you want to see how the parameters are used to create the link. You don't need to implement [`CHtml`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml) yourself, it is already part of the framework.